# ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer when deploy war in WebLogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic

When I deploy my Spring Boot project package as war WebLogic throws:

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1025)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:986)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:607)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:539)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:492)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:469)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1390)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1360)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1907)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3091)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1849)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:882)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:754)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:264)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:627)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:347)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:901)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1456)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:456)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

WebLogic Server Version: **12.2.1.1.0**

My Spring Boot source:

**OneAppAPI.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OneAppAPI extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(OneAppAPI.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OneAppAPI.class, args);
    }
```

**weblogic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app         http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:context-root>oneapp</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

**dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

My dependency scope for spring-boot-starter-tomcat is *provided* and xml files are placed in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/

I've installed in other WebLogic but with different version (12.2.1.3.0) and it works.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Ditch the `dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml` and also add the `org.springframewor` packages to the `Weblogic.xml`... Weblogic ships its own version of Spring currently the ones from the server are preferred over the packaged ones.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the prefered packages, I posted full `weblogic.xml`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get the solution, as M. Deinum comments, the problem was the WebLogic packages, but in my case, I also have to add

```
   <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>*
```